# Require dependency of another dependency in node modules

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm, node-modules

I've got a simple node app that has single dependency on another app on github. The dependency installs just fine with `npm install`, but when I try to require something installed there, it says it's not available. For example, the github app installs Mongoose as a dependency. I thought that this parent app would be able to access that module since it is in a child:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

The structure looks something like this:

```
/app
  /node_modules
    /github_dependency [parent module]
      /node_modules
        /mongoose [child module]
```

Do I just have to include mongoose as a dependency as well in the parent app or is there a way of getting access to that module by way of the child?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Do I just have to include mongoose as a dependency as well in the parent app or is there a way of getting access to that module by way of the child?

While it's *possible* for you to e.g. `require('github/node_modules/mongoose')`, the standard practice is to install all of your dependencies explicitly (i.e., you should include mongoose as a dependency of your app) and `require('mongoose')`.

Comment: Thank you, we'll follow this convention. One thing I did want to mention, is this could theoretically result in multiple, duplicate dependencies in the project?

Comment: It could, and you will typically have several instances of several different modules (and version thereof) in a node project. That's one of the strengths of npm IMO, having spent a sizeable part of the '00s working out kinks in the class loaders of different Java containers...

Comment: There's a very good reason to use this technique.  If you do a require of ('github/node_modules/mongoose'), you are using the same instance of mongoose that github is using, so you share it's connection pool.   This technique is also useful to ensure you're using the same versions.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the dependency will live inside a nested `node_module`. IIUC, if the same version of the dependency is used by another module, it may be hoisted to the root `node_modules`.

Comment: I would say that if you control the upstream project and it is handling mongoose logic, i.e. a special orm case, one should have that upstream project resolve the dependencies explicitly while all consumers of your tailored mongoose orm module ought to use the version of mongoose defined in said tailored mongoose module. 

In this case, because you do not have control over the upstream project, you ought to explicitly define your dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

For a more robust case, which is good in situations such as testing, you can use the following function:

```
var Module = require('module');
var path = require('path');

function requireFrom(self, parent, name) {
  var pPath = Module._resolveFilename(parent, self);
  var m = new Module(pPath, module);
  m.filename = pPath;
  m.paths = Module._nodeModulePaths(path.dirname(pPath));
  return m.require(name);
}
```

which can be used as follows

```
requireFrom(module, 'github_dependency', 'mongoose')
```

Comment: What is the `self` argument supposed to be? I can't tell from the context.

Comment: ^ Ignore my comment. I am a nodejs n00b and did not realize that `module` was itself a reserved keyword!!!

Comment: Note that it's not a reserved keyword, it's a builtin per-module variable that is automatically added via the wrapper. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper