# use npm module of dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

The context:

1. my app  depends on a module 'my-module'
2. 'my-module' depends on 'express'
3. I want to `require('express')` form my app
   without need of installing 'express' dependecy in my app directly but instead I want it to be taken from 'my-module'.

Is it possible to configure npm/package.json work this why? Maybe `npm link` should be used, I just not sure if it is a standard scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several possible solutions for your problem.

#### Explicit export

If you're the one who maintains `my-module` and this is one of its common use cases, then you should explicitly `export` any important dependency to be used in parent application.

This solution is preferable for handy utility modules, but it doesn't look like a good solution for modules like `express`.

#### Relying on npm

If you just want to eliminate duplicate dependencies, then you could add `express` to your parent application. If any of your application dependencies will also depend on `express`, `npm` will use already installed one (provided that there is no version mismatch).

This solution is preferable if `my-module` is a third-party module.

#### Using [peer dependencies](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/)

Again, if you're the one who maintains `my-module` you could specify `express` an a `peerDependency`. By doing so you'll tell `npm` to always use `express` module from the parent application.

This solution is preferable for framework modules like `express` and `mongoose`.

#### Using the most direct approach

If none of those solution fits you for some reason, you could `require` any dependency of another dependency [using the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736561/1202461):

```
require('my-module/node_modules/express')
```

Just try to avoid this approach if you can.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that perr dependencies is the way to go in my case!

Comment: The problem with peerDeps though that they are not longer installed automatically the app should depend on them explicitly =(