# How to reliably locate/import a dependency of a dependency?

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to import a dependency of a dependency. For example, I want to import `jade-load` directly into my app:

```
my-app
 ┗━jade
   ┗━jade-load
```

I could do `require('jade/node_modules/jade-load')`, but this won't work if the node_modules tree has been flattened or deduped.

I thought of using `require.resolve()` to find out where `jade-load` really is, but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell it the *starting point* for the resolution. I need to be able to say "require jade-load from wherever jade is".

NB. I do not want to install jade-load as a direct dependency of my app; the point is to import the same instance that jade uses, so I can monkeypatch it.

Comment: Somewhat of a duplicate here however it probably isn't the answer your looking for.  I'm not aware of a reliable way to load a module in the fashion your speaking of.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736514/require-dependency-of-another-dependency-in-node-modules

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's only two locations where the module can exist: in `node_modules/jade/node_modules` or in `node_modules/`. Why not try both?

Comment: @robertklep - what if my module is actually a dependency of something else? Then it's technically possible that the dep I want to load might exist somewhere like `../../../node_modules/`.

Comment: @callum I assumed that you wanted to load it from a "top-level" app, not a separate module.

Comment: @robertklep I want to know how to do it in general, so could be for modules or top-level apps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want to use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) for managing dependencies of required modules. You can set proxyquire to globally override methods of the submodule when it will be loaded.

main.js

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

// use default childModule properties and methods unless they are redefined here
var childModuleStub = {
  /* redefine here some necessary methods */
  '@global': true
};
// parent module itself does't require childModule
var parentModuleStubs = {
  './childModule': childModuleStub
};

var parentModule = proxyquire('./parentModule', parentModuleStubs);

var result;

result = parentModule.exec();
console.log(result);

childModuleStub.data.sentence = "Overridden property.";
result = parentModule.exec();
console.log(result);

childModuleStub._exec = function () {
  return "Overridden function.";
};
result = parentModule.exec();
console.log(result);
```

parentModule.js

```
var intermediateLibrary = require('./intermediateLibrary');

module.exports = {
  exec: function() {
    return intermediateLibrary.exec();
  }
};
```

intermediateLibrary.js

```
var childModule = require('./childModule');

module.exports = {
  exec: function() {
    return childModule._exec();
  }
};
```

childModule.js

```
var lib = {};

lib.data = {};
lib.data.sentence = "Hello, World!";
lib._exec = function () {
  return lib.data.sentence;
};

module.exports = lib;
```

Results:

```
Hello, World!
Overridden property.
Overridden function.
```