# Why is using a dependency of another dependency a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, npm

As the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736514/require-dependency-of-another-dependency-in-node-modules) states, the standard practice is to install packages from sub-dependencies that should be used in the app again instead of using it out of the dependencies node_modules folder.

My case is a little different. We have three projects that share the same front end 'core'. To keep the dependencies in sync we install dependencies like slick-slider and node-sass only in our core and access them from our project in which we install the core as a npm dependency.

Are there any downsides beside not seeing the dependency list directly in the project package.json?

Comment: Obviously if you ever were to _not_ use that core but use another core you'd have to make sure that the new core includes the same dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you control the 'core' then I would say it's not too big of an issue. However it could cause problems if you do not own the package, as it could change it's dependencies at any time and break your code.

Comment: I agree with Jim. I would state that if you control the 'core' then it is actually a solid dependency management strategy to use that core project's modules to ensure compatibility between your two own projects.