# How import module dependencies from other npm dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm, module, dependencies

I have the following question. Currently I want to build a NPM module which this expected behaviour:

Once I've installed it, all its dependencies would work perfectly in the project only import them.

First of all, what I have is this:

[image]

I have "my-module" project as the dependencies modules I want with that specific versions.

On the other hand I have a project which imports it as we can see.

Inside my project I want to write, for example, the following code and finally run it:

```
import {Calendar} from 'primereact/calendar';
```

How could I deal with this trouble?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My project's package.json is this

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next src",
    "build": "next build src",
    "start": "next start src"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^9.0.3",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "@ascope/my-module": "file://../my-module"
  }
}
```

Also my-module's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "primereact",
    "rxjs"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "primereact": "^3.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "primereact": "^3.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both packages will need the `primereact` dependency, when you do an `install` on the top level package it will move the `primereact` dependency up, assuming there's a version that can satisfy both dependencies.

Have a look at [NPM install algorithm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm)

> For this package{dep} structure: A{B,C}, B{C}, C{D}, this algorithm
>   produces:

```
A
+-- B
+-- C
+-- D
```

> That is, the dependency from B to C is satisfied by the fact that A
>   already caused C to be installed at a higher level. D is still
>   installed at the top level because nothing conflicts with it.

---

> For A{B,C}, B{C,D@1}, C{D@2}, this algorithm produces:

```
A
+-- B
+-- C
   `-- D@2
+-- D@1
```

> Because B’s D@1 will be installed in the top level, C now has to
>   install D@2 privately for itself. This algorithm is deterministic, but
>   different trees may be produced if two dependencies are requested for
>   installation in a different order.

You can also run [`npm dedupe`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe.html)

Comment: So there is no any solution to make a "version's dependencies manager" package module?

Comment: If by that you mean a way to manage package dependencies of your dependencies from a top level package then no. Each package needs to have their dependencies declared and the package manager will manage the location of your dependencies for you. So if both your packages need `primereact` then both will need `primereact` in their `package.json`

Comment: The only purpose of this module was to manage dependencies for later import only that module and do not mind for dependencies

Comment: @mryuso92 there's no way to do that, you are better off with scaffolding techniques to reuse dependencies across your projects

Answer (score 0):

In node.js, it is recommended that you declare those dependencies specifically as a part of your app.

[Require dependency of another dependency in node modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736514/require-dependency-of-another-dependency-in-node-modules)

Comment: The problem I have experimented with this is the application is missing some dependencies. For example, if I import React Calendar, builder is giving me an error about "classnames" import. Thanks anyway :)