# Yarn import from nested dependency

Tags: javascript, import, dependencies, yarnpkg

My node_modules already has package B at top level, and I have package A depends on package B

I want to import something directly from package B in package A's node_modules, how do I do that?

I want something like `import ../node_modules/package-a/package-b`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025043/1229023) seems to answer your question, unless you need to `import` only, and `require` won't fit your case. Can't help wondering why exactly you need to depend on two different versions of the same package in your app. :)

Comment: I need it because the top level package is a dependency of another package